# Chosen with Jquery validator show error with the chosen search text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

In my project I am using `chosen` dropdown with `Jquery validator`. I added `ignore: []` in the validation function. Now the issue is,

**the validator validating the search text box with in the chosen plugin and showing the below error in the debug**

[image]

**In my page, there are 3 chosen select as showing in the below image**

[image]

The above error is showing for the text field showing below **Which is automatically generated by the chosen plugin and it don't have a name**

[image]

The sample code which I am using for validation is

```
function validateUserForm() {
$('#user-master-form').validate({
    debug: true,
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 100
        },
        last_name: {
            maxlength: 100
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            maxlength: 15,
            minlength: 10
        },
        date_of_birth: {
            required: true
        },
        gender: {
            required: true
        },
        address: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 200
        },
        state: {
            required: true
        },
        district: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        first_name: {
            required: "Please enter first name",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!"),
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Up to {0} characters allowed!")
        },
        last_name: {
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Up to {0} characters allowed!")
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter email id",
            email: 'Invalid email format',
        },
        mobile: {
            required: "Please enter mobile",
            number: 'Only numbers allowed',
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} numbers required!"),
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Up to {0} numbers allowed!")
        },
        date_of_birth: {
            required: "Please enter date of birth"
        },
        gender: {
            required: "Please select gender"
        },
        address: {
            required: "Please enter address",
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Up to {0} characters allowed!")
        },
        state: {
            required: "Please select state"
        },
        district: {
            required: "Please select district"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.hasClass("chosen")) {
            var id = element.attr('id');
            error.insertAfter("#" + id + "_chosen");
        }
        else if (element.parent('.vd_radio').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Please help me to get rid of this issue. I am stuck on here. Any help could be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First Fix : Provide name attribute to the <input> tags
Second Fix : If the above elements are generated by plugin, the place `"input[type=text&autocomplete=off]"` in ignore field of jquery validator.

Comment: Not possible as it is created by the chosen plugin

Comment: @Arun : Please try with the sSecond Fix, keeping in mind that you don't provide "autocomplete=off" in any of the text fields.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that it is not possible to add names via plugin, you can add names to the input fields by using `.each()` loop. This should eliminate the error. Eg below:

```
var names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each('#idOrClass input', function(i) {
        $(this).attr('name', names[i]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This is a crack which I already thought about. But is there any other way with out this?

Comment: You can hide the message by using `:not` like `ignore: '*:not([name])'`